# Arrays in C - Lvalue vs. R-Value

Tags: arrays, c, rvalue, lvalue

I have a question regarding the definitions of lValues and rValues in C and where arrays fit in:
I always thought that arrays, e.g.

```
int arr[10];
```

are non-modifiable lValues. However, if you use them like modifiable lValues, like e.g. here:`arr++;`, and try to compile it, I don't get the expected error message. The message is "lvalue required as increment operand". For other nonmodifiable lValues, such as constants, the message is "increment of read-only variable".
Why is that?

Comment: Specific diagnostic messages are a function of the individual implementation; you'd have to ask whoever wrote that compiler why they use those specific messages.  But note that constants are not non-modifiable lvalues, they are *rvalues* (they do not designate a memory location), so the compiler is likely going down different processing paths for one vs. the other, so it's not surprising the error messages are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we were going to try to evaluate `arr++`, then C 2018 6.3.2.1 3 tells us that `arr` is first converted to a pointer to its first element:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of *type*” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to *type*” that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue…

So, if we make that conversion and then work on the `++`, we find that the operand of `++` is just a value, not an lvalue. And hence the error message that an lvalue is required for the operand of an increment.

A compiler can give a different message, of course; the C standard is not strict about what has to be said in the diagnostic messages.

Comment: Can a value be neither lvalue nor rvalue? I thought it would have to be one or the other...

Comment: @Mary: The C standard uses the term “value,” not “rvalue.” Where do you see anything here that is neither an lvalue nor a value? The array is an lvalue. It is converted to a pointer to its first element, resulting in a value. A value that is not an lvalue cannot be the operand of `++`.

Comment: I said neither lvalue nor R value.... what I mean is that I thought a C standard value is always either R value or a L value...

Comment: @Mary: Again, where do you see anything here that is neither an lvalue or an rvalue?

Comment: "So, if we make that conversion and then work on the ++, we find that the operand of ++ is just a value, not an lvalue." So it is a value, but no lvalue and rvalue, right?

Comment: @Mary: The C standard does not use the term “rvalue.” Every expression has a value. Some of those are lvalues. (So there are two types of values in C: values that are lvalues and values that are not lvalues.) The term “rvalue” as used elsewhere is just a value in C. `arr` is an lvalue, because it designates the array. It is converted to a pointer to its first element. The resulting pointer is just a value. That is an “rvalue” as the term is used elsewhere, but the C standard just calls it a value (that is not an lvalue).

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160 :

> Any of the following C expressions can be l-value expressions:
>
> - An identifier of integral, floating, pointer, structure, or union type
> - A subscript ([ ]) expression that does not evaluate to an array
> - A member-selection expression (-> or .)
> - A unary-indirection (*) expression that does not refer to an array
> - An l-value expression in parentheses
> - A const object (a nonmodifiable l-value)

I guess an array simply is not a lvalue. However a subscript of an array (that is not an array of array !) is one.

Comment: Arrays are lvalues. The Microsoft documentation is wrong. As an example, the operand of unary `&` must be a function designator, the result of `[]`, the result of unary `*`, or an lvalue (C 2018 6.5.3.2 1). But you can take the address of an array, as with `&arr`. That is because `arr` is indeed an lvalue, as it is not a function designator, the result of `[]`, or the result of unary `*`, although you can also get an array lvalue as the result of `[]` or unary `*`. Arrays are just rarely used as lvalues as they are automatically converted to pointers in most expressions.